# How to put character or separator before a string in R

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

I have a string like :

```
"Father’s Name : ABC NaskarDate of Birth : 18-01-1979Permanent Address: This is the address field for the personContact Numbers : 98413***28Passport Number:PAN Number: AEFXXXXXXXLanguages Known: Tamil, English"
```

My desired output is :

```
"|||Father’s Name : ABC Naskar|||Date of Birth : 18-01-1979|||Permanent Address: This is the address field for the person|||Contact Numbers : 98413***28|||Passport Number:|||PAN Number: AEFXXXXXXX|||Languages Known: Tamil, English"
```

That means I want to add "|||" before some specific strings like Father’s Name,
Date of Birth etc.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not able to find a general pattern, but based on the string showed, it seems that the `|||` separator should be at the start (`^`) of the string, whereever there is a lower case letter followed by upper case or number followed by upper case, also before `PAN` and between `XXXX` and `Languages`.  In that case, a regex lookaround should work.

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|^|(?<=[XXX])(?=Lang)|(?=PAN)", "|||", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "|||Father’s Name : ABC Naskar|||Date of Birth : 18-01-1979|||Permanent Address: This is the address field for the person|||Contact Numbers : 98413***28|||Passport Number:|||PAN Number: AEFXXXXXXX|||Languages Known: Tamil, English"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Father’s Name : ABC NaskarDate of Birth : 18-01-1979Permanent Address: This is the address field for the personContact Numbers : 98413***28Passport Number:PAN Number: AEFXXXXXXXLanguages Known: Tamil, English"
```

Comment: But before Language I am getting "B" also if PAN number is end with "B"          Like : "PAN Number: AEF***35|||BLanguages Known: Tamil, English"             Here PAN no. was AEF***35B. Thanks..

Comment: @A.Naskar As I stated in the solution, I was not sure about the patterns In that case you need one more pattern there `(?=BLang)`

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(Father’s Name)|(Date of Birth)", "|||\\1\\2", x)
[1] "|||Father’s Name : ABC Naskar|||Date of Birth : 18-01-1979Permanent Address: This is the address field for the personContact Numbers : 98413***28Passport Number:PAN Number: AEFXXXXXXXLanguages Known: Tamil, English"
```

Fortunately the regex OR, `"|"`, is able to get distributed in the substitution with the second pattern.